# Несколько OpenGLControl'ов на одной форме WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, sharpgl

Я использую WPF и SharpGL, чтобы отрисовать нужные мне графики. На форме у меня 2 OpenGLControl, однако отрисовка происходит только в одном, я не понимаю, почему это так работает. В коде я обращаюсь к каждому control'у по его имени, но это не помогает. Как это  решить?
Использую .net 6.

Comment: Где-то в коде ошибка.

Comment: Не думаю. Я получаю OpenGL через имя каждого из control'ов, при первом запуске графики есть в обоих control'ах, но после первого же обновления рисунки остаются только в одном из них

Comment: GL для 2Д в WPF, который сам использует DirectX и может нарисовать сам эти графики, зачем?

Comment: Ну мне так нужно. Просто по заданию.

Comment: Вот [мой старый ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536945/12888024), как самому графики рисовать. А так есть не мало готовых библиотек, которые вам какие угодно графики нарисуют. Что касается самой проблемы, без кода, который не работает, невозможно понять, в чем она заключается. А так "через имя" в WPF не делают, в WPF используют привязки данных. Сделайте воспроизводимый пример, без него не разберемся.